# Something is wrong with my insert query php form

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to insert data in my database without success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... No error appears... Maybe my file path is wrong? I'm using prepared statements. I've been inserting data in several databases for as long as I can remember without problem. First time this is happening to me.

**File path logic:**

```
-includes
--config.php
-user
--tables
---form.php
---query.php
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); 
session_start();
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'myDB');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

**form.php**

```
<form  id="addNewCompanyForm" class="form" method="POST" action="query.php">

   <input id='titleName' class='form-control formBlock' name='title' value='' type='text' placeholder="Name...">

<select id='type' class='form-control formBlock' name='type'></select> 


      <textarea  id='description' class='form-control formBlock' name='description' value='' placeholder="Enter details here..."></textarea>


    <input id='address' class='form-control formBlock' name='address' value='' type='text' placeholder="Address">

<select name="country"  id='country' class='form-control formBlock' name='country' value='' type='text' placeholder="Country"></select> 

      <select id='timezone' class='form-control formBlock' name="timezone"></select> 


     <input id="submit" type="submit" class="formBlock btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" value="Enter Data"/>
</form>
```

**query.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../../includes/config.php';

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO companystructures (title, description, address, type, country, timezone) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $title, $type, $description, $address, $country, $timezone);

// set parameters and execute
$title =  $_POST['title'];
$type =  $_POST['type'];
$description=  $_POST['description'];

$address =  $_POST['address'];
$country =  $_POST['country'];
$timezone =  $_POST['timezone'];
$stmt->execute();

//echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: for one thing, you have no `<option>` with values for `<select>`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks but i'm just trying to keep the code short. My form is way too long. Saving you a lot of pain.

Comment: use php's error reporting and check for errors on the query with `mysqli_error($db)`.